# Unable to update attributes of association objects using factory girl and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

So, I have a factory that produces a user with a couple of associations.  Instead of creating a new factory for each case, I'd like to create the object and modify some attributes of the association objects.

```
let(:user) do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_associations)
    user.associations.where(some_id: user.default_thing.id).first.some_attribute = Time.now
    user.save
    user
end
```

But if I call `puts user.associations.to_yaml` in an `it` block, it does not have the updated attribute of `some_attribute = Time.now`.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know factory-girl, nor respc but you could try `xxxx.first.update_attribute(:some_attribute, Time.now)` and/or a `user.reload` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions...

First, you seem to be working *against* FactoryGirl's strength. A better approach IMHO is to move your customization code into a factory, for example define a FactoryGirl factory for whatever you're building.

Example:

```
 let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_time_now) }
```

This is really the whole point of FactoryGirl IMHO.

Second, if you're using Rails and ActiveRecord, look at :inverse_of for associations. These tell ActiveRecord that the associations should loop back to the original object.